# Permitir somente tecla delete

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho o script abaixo, que bloqueia toda digitação em um input, obrigando o usuário a usar o `DatePicker` disponibilizado:

```
            $(".readonly").keydown(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Nesse mesmo script, existe como eu permitir o acesso somente a tecla `delete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, podes fazer da seguinte maneira

```
$(".readonly").keydown(function(e){
    if( e.keyCode !== 46 ){ // 46 é tecla delete  
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas testei em 2 locais e não funcionou....

Comment: resposta editada, tenta com novo codigo

Comment: se não resultar tenta trocar `which` para `keyCode`

Comment: Funcionou com o keyCode. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ah estava a achar estranho , espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

O código da tecla <kbd>delete</kbd> é o 46. Você só irá executar `e.preventDefault();` se for diferente de <kbd>delete</kbd>. Todo evento no Jquery recebe um parâmetro, nesse caso `e`, nele você pode acessar o `keycode` do evento `.keydown` sendo assim só fazer a verificação com o valor da tecla `delete`.

```
$(".readonly").keydown(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode != 46 ){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: `if(e.keyCode !== 46 )`

Comment: Mas ai é comparação de tipos não ? Se aplica ? Ao meu ver pode até funcionar, mas acho desnecessário, me corrija se eu estiver errado.